# Create a function for a number of lists and correctly group the list elements

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have 3 lists, but sometimes only 2, that each contain 4 multi-index dataframes.

```
list1=[df1, df2, df3, df4]
list2=[df1_, df2_, df3_, df4_]
list3=[df1__, df2__, df3__, df4__]
```

The next step is to create multi-index dataframes:

```
reportTable1 = list1[0].round(2) #this dataframe is equal to list1[0], In other words "df1".
reportTable2 = pd.concat([list1[1], list2[1], list3[1]], axis = 0).round(2) #these dataframes have different columns.
reportTable3 = pd.concat([list1[2], list2[2], list3[2]], axis = 0).round(2) #they have same columns.
reportTable4 = pd.concat([list1[3], list2[3], list3[3]], axis = 0).applymap('{:.2%}'.format) #they have same columns.
```

Firstly, I want to define a function for these steps with cleaner code.

My main problem is that in some cases `list3` doesn't exit. In this situation, I do not want to get error. How can I run this code in cases where `list3` is not available?

Comment: I'm glad the solution worked for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late conversion. Thank you so much, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The following function will work if there are only two `lists` of `dataframes`.

  - The `lists` of `dataframes` are passed to the function as [`*args`](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#using-the-python-args-variable-in-function-definitions), so any number of `lists` can be passed to the function.
- The type annotations indicate the `*args` are a `list` of `dataframes`, and a `tuple` of `dataframes` is returned by the function.
- `list(zip(*v))` is used to create the correct groups of `dataframes` for `pandas.concat`.
- The number of tables, `t#`, returned by the function corresponds to the number of `dataframes` in the `lists`.

  - If the `lists` contain more than the number of dataframes shown (e.g. `df5`, `df5_` and `df5__`, then add a line of code to the function for `t5` and `return` it.

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import List, Tuple  # for type annotations

# function to create report tables
def my_func(*v: List[pd.DataFrame]) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame]:
    l = list(zip(*v))  # use zip to combine the dataframes into the correct groups
    t1 = l[0][0].round(2)  # l[0] = (df1, df1_, df1__) → l[0][0] = df1
    t2 = pd.concat(l[1]).round(2)  # l[1] = (df2, df2_, df2__)
    t3 = pd.concat(l[2]).round(2)  # l[2] = (df3, df3_, df3__)
    t4 = pd.concat(l[3]).applymap('{:.2%}'.format)  # l[3] = (df4, df4_, df4__)
    return t1, t2, t3, t4


# data
l1 = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
l2 = [df1_, df2_, df3_, df4_]
l3 = [df1__, df2__, df3__, df4__]

# function call with 3 lists
rt1, rt2, rt3, rt4 = my_func(l1, l2, l3)

# function call with 2 lists
rt1, rt2, rt3, rt4 = my_func(l1, l2)
```